# parentheses around a formula result

Tags: parentheses, display

How do I display the results of a formula -- e.g. "=(a1/b1)" which might return "45%" -- so that the result is surrounded by parens and appears as "(45%)"?  Putting parens around the formula -- e.g. "(=(a1/b1))" -- doesn't work.

Comment: Which environment are you talking about? Excel? Please tag your question accordingly.

Comment: If it is Excel, then use a custom format for your cell.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean in Excel? you can just set the format of the cell. how it should show the result.

Just right click on the Cell then format cells and then chose percentage on the left hand side. then change it to custome and put some parentheses arround the result. thats it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the language you're using.

If `=(a1/b1)` works to give you `"45%"` then I would trying this: `"(" + =(a1/b1) + ")"`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but I thought it might be of interest for others as well.

To clarify the answer since it did not work for me when I tried it. In order to put the result from a function/formula within two parentheses in the same cell you need to use this function:

```
="("&(Cellfunction)&")".
```

In your case that would look like this:

```
="("&(A1/B1)&")".
```

If you have the same problem as the one asking the question, try copy/paste this funtion into a blank cell in a new sheet in Excel and type `1` into cell `A1` and `2` into cell `B1`.

When using the funcion in the blank cell (for example `C1`) the result should be `0,5`. This function also works for displaying parentheses around a returned answer. For example: Cell `D252` displays the result from Cell `C7` (`C7` could have its own function/formula). That's how I used the function which looked like this:

```
="("&(C7)&")"
```

Hope this helps,
Best,
Felix, Business administration student in Sweden

I'm using Mac and Excel for Mac Home and Student 2011.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to format the cells. Choose Custom on the left side. Then in the empty field type in:

(0)

This will put your value in parentheses. If you want the value to be carried to 1 decimal place then type in:

(0.0)

etc.